# Debian - python has two dist-packages? Which one should i use?

Tags: python, debian, pyserial

I have noticed, that Debian has two dist-packages for Python, one in:

```
usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

and the other one in:

```
usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

I am having trouble to get Python to recognize the pyserial library correctly (I installed it via `pip install pyserial`). I wonder if `pip` may use the wrong dist-packages path?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You can print out the value of ``sys.path`` inside of the Python interpreter to see what the Python module search path is.

Comment: pip uses site-packages

Answer (score 1):

The packages in `/usr/lib` is handled by the packages you install via `apt`and the packages in `/usr/local/lib` is handled by for instance `pip` or `easy_install` .

Comment: pip uses site-packages

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but which one is actually used by the system? For example, i have installed an SDK which uses the pyserial module to communicate with devices over USB but it doesn't detect the pyserial module even though i have installed it via pip and via apt-get install.

Comment: Okay, the solution was to move the serial folder installed by `sudo apt-get install python-serial` to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` to get recognized.